# how to access user control placed in master pages's user control

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I need to access a user control from master page but user control is not placed directly in master page. It has this hierarchic:

***Master Page  > HeaderUserControl > LoginUserControl > Login button and Logout botton***

Requirement:

I need to call logout method of logout button. Unfortunately I am not getting what can be best design to do that.

Please advise and help.

Thanks

Comment: Ideally your logout logic wouldn't be in the codebehind for the user control.. it would be in a separate class that both pages can call.

Comment: just use events or model data bindings.

Answer (score 0):

create a httphandler and move the code of logout and you may use it by calling the handler.

Answer (score 0):

As @SimonWhitehead said, you should add a class and call the Logout method from both the `MasterPage` and the `LoginControl`. But if you insist, this is a way of doing it, pretty much making the method visible to the next level:

**LoginUserControl**:

```
Public Sub DoLogout()
    'Do something'
End Sub

Protected Sub Logout_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Logout.Click
    DoLogout()
End Sub
```

**HeaderUserControl**:

```
Public Sub DoLogout()
    Me.LoginUserControl.DoLogout()
End Sub
```

and finally

**MasterPage**:

```
Protected Sub Logout_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Logout.Click
    HeaderUserControl.DoLogout()
End Sub
```

This would call your method in the `LoginUserControl` control.